# Solving an integral for $\pi^2/6$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So the above value is the result of the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}x {\rm d}y}{1-xy} \, .
$$
I'm playing around to find a substitution for which this integral is actually solvable in terms of elementary functions.

Does anyone know of one or more?

edit: I actually found one substitution in Proof3 of http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/basel-problem.pdf, but I think there are others.

Comment: You can integrate $x$ first to get $-\int_0^1 \log(1-y)/y \, dy$, and then use a power series expansion for $\log(1-y)$. The resulting series sums to $\pi^2/6$. Not sure if that qualifies as elementary functions.

Comment: No it does not, because that is what I want to calculate.
I think I have actually seen some fancy transformation involving something like $x=\tan(u)\tan(v)$ and likewise something for $y$, but I dont remember.

Comment: This is $\zeta(2)$ and it's not an elementary functions.

Comment: Look in the link and you'll know what I mean by "elementary"

Comment: It has many pages, you may simply write $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xy}dxdy=\int_0^1\frac{-\ln{(1-x)}}{x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^n}{n}dx=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)$$

Comment: One trick is to use the substitution $(u,v)=(x+y,y-x)$.

Comment: Probably you mean $x=u-v$ and $y=u+v$. That is the route followed in the link if people would click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's solvable using but only elementary functions, but I do know it can solved as follows:

$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{1}{1-x y}dxdy = \int_0^1 -\frac{\log{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}+\frac{\log{\left(1\right)}}{y} dy= \int_0^1 -\frac{\log{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}dy$$

This can be integrated and becomes the [polylogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html):

$$\text{Li}_2\left(y\right) \\ \text{Li}_2\left(1\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\ \text{Li}_2\left(0\right)=0 \\ \frac{\pi^2}{6}-0=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: polylog is not elementary in my opinion.

Comment: OK, but I'd suggest looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) for more info and maybe leads on an answer